# ListContourPlot throw error when Log used in ColorFunction

Tags: plotting

When I run

```
ListContourPlot[Table[10^(x + y), {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], 
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][(Log10@# + 4)/2] &)]
```

Mathematica throws 'Blend is not a Graphics order'.

However,

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[10^(x + y), {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], 
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][(Log10@# + 4)/2] &)]
```

works fine. What's wrong?

Comment: works fine (no error message) in version 12 (wolfram cloud)

Comment: puzzling.. The question is not how to fix the issue; but in version 9 (windows 10) adding the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` fixes it.

Comment: If you `Trace[ListContourPlot[...], _Blend, TraceInternal -> True]` (and the same for `ListDensityPlot`) both generate `Blend["Rainbow", Indeterminate]` but somehow `ListDensityPlot` does not complain.